# Quantum algorithm with $|y\rangle \mapsto (-1)^{xy}|y\rangle$ for all $y$ with at most $T$ many $1$s

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, simons-algorithm

Given an N-bit string $x$, which we can access by queries, give a quantum algorithm that maps $$|y\rangle \mapsto (-1)^{xy}|y\rangle$$ for all $y \in \{0,1\}^{N}$ that have at most T many $1$s and the algorithm uses T many queries on x.

This is an exercise in the lecture notes of Ronald de Wolf. It seems pretty intuitive since we wouldn't need more than T queries because it can't be, that more than T many bits of $x$ matter for the product $xy$. But I can't figure it out.